# How to use a C:\ folder to store images in a IIS Server (.NET MVC 4)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

Webservices are uploading images to a specific folder in the server "C:\UploadedImages\".
So i want them to be accesible to the world from my MVC 4 app, stored in the same IIS server.
How can i manage to do that?
Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you need is a virtualpath, like this one

```
<application path="/uploads" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\UploadedImages" />
</application>
```

application path is the virtualized url: http://www.yourserver.com/uploads
and physicalPath is the path at your server where images really are